# PDO Exception when value passed dynamically

Tags: php, pdo, constraints

I have a simple insertion code of PDO to MYSQL database.

This is my code.

```
$catinsert="insert into shop_detail(shop_id,sub_category_id)values(:shop_id,:subcatid)";

$catresult=$pdocon->prepare($catinsert);

foreach($catexplode as $catval)
{
    $subcat=$catval;
//  $subcat=6;
    $catresult->bindValue(':shop_id',$shopid,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $catresult->bindValue(':subcatid',$subcat,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $catresult->execute();
}
```

When I pass the **static value** for $subcat (which is commented out) then it works just fine. But when that same value is being passed through array and bounded then it returns the exception for **foreign key integrity violation**.

For sake of background to this question. I have foreign key relating my sub_category_id column of shop_detail table to *sub_category* table with same column name.

***Importantly.*** 
The value which is being bound and to be inserted, do exist in my *sub_category* table.

---

Here is the **detailed error**.

> `` exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`list`.`shop_detail`, CONSTRAINT `shop_to_subcat` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_category_id`) REFERENCES `sub_category` (`sub_category_id`))' in somewhat file. ``

Comment: Can you post a var_dump of $catexplode ?

Comment: @Bert Thanks a lot.. As far as I know the reason behind your asking for var_dump was to check the data type. And I straight way converted my variable to integer and that worked for me. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you're doing that wrong. You should bind ONCE outside of the loop:

```
$subcat = null;
$stmt->bindParam(':subcatid', $subcat);
foreach($catexplode as $subcat) {
   $stmt->execute();
}
```

The whole point of binding a variable to a placeholder is that you only do the binding ONCE. Internally PHP will set up what amounts to a pointer/reference to the bound variable, so that any changes in the value of the variable will be picked up when you actually execute the statement.

Comment: Thanks @Marc B for the interest and correction. Though the problem was of data type and I finally got it solved by converting the string to integer explicitly..